# Change Mime Type Response From Text to JSON For Declarative External Services

Tags: api, visual-workflow, external-services

OpenApi 2.0 or 3.0 declarative External Services used in Flow getting error `Expected declared response media type application/json, but got text/plain; charset=UTF-8 for operation get`. It appears 3rd party changed response header to `text/plain` despite the response being a well-formatted JSON.

Looking for a way for External Services to recognize this as a JSON despite the header. Would likely need to do this as part of schema to ensure that the Apex variables can be correctly mapped. This is a managed package.

Comment: You can take the OpenAPI schema for the external service and add text/plain as a response type: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/ . You might be able to remap text/plain to application/json handler via Metadata API as described in this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_services_mime_type_mapping.htm&type=5)

Comment: Tks that doesn't work though. When include text/plain as a response the Apex Classes don't get created on backend. Mapping also doesn't work b/c text/plain is a supported response type so any mapping is skipped by Salesforce. The [produces examples](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.external_services_schema_examples.htm&type=5) suggest multiple types accepted but error seems to only read first one listed.